# Where can I add assertion in SoapUi 5.1.3. I am not able to find that tiny assertion button in this version of SoapUI

Tags: web-services, soapui

I was going through SoapUI tutorial. But not able to find the assertion button in SoapUI version 5.1.3. Can you please suggest me where can I find that assertion button in SoapUI, and start doing my assertions.

Thank you.

Comment: make sure your request is within a test suite.  requests not in a test suite don't have an assertions tab.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question you want to create an assertion for your testStep. So when you create a `TestStep` of different types like `HTTP Test Request`, `SOAP Test Request` etc... you can add `assertions` to your testSteps using assertion button in the bottom of the window, like in the follow image:

[image]

Additionally you can also make asserts of your testSteps using groovy testStep.